# How to set FullCalendar to a specific date after event creation?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've noticed some strange behaviour from the jQuery plugin FullCalendar. For example, an administrator creates an event in August while we're in June, he wants to add another event in August but the calender brings him back to June when he tries to add another event.

Is it possible to set the date to the last created event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call below method for add new event click.

```
var date = 'Store last event date here';
.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', date )
```